# How to reduce disk-space requirements of Bitcoin Core wallet?

Tags: wallet

I want to install Bitcoin Core wallet on my computer, but his blockchain is too big (more 230 Gb).

How to reduce Bitcoin Core wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `prune` option to specify the amount of disk space you would like Bitcoin Core to use. This option allows you to keep only the latest block information instead of storing all the data.

1. find your configuration file `bitcoin.conf` ([here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin) you can find the list of possible locations depending on your operating system);
2. set `prune` parameter to the desired target size in MiB (for example, `prune=2048`);
3. restart the wallet.